# How to animate the resize of a Delphi VCL form on Windows?

Tags: forms, delphi, animation, resize, vcl

Is there any reasonably simple and robust way to *smoothly animate* the programmatic resize of a Delphi VCL form on Windows?

For instance, when the user clicks the "Show details" button the form's height is increased with a details panel shown in the new client area.

Resizing the form by setting its `Height` (or `ClientHeight`) property will resize it immediately. I want the form to grow smoothly in height from its original value to the new value over a half-second duration.

How to smoothly animate the resize of a Delphi VCL form?

Comment: Reminds me how I was a fan of [`AnimateWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow) 20 years ago and at some point hated **all** animations for wasting my time. Give the user an option to disable animations, please, or respect system settings.

Comment: Here's an old question with a simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953650/delphi-smooth-collapse-expand-form/36956429#36956429

Comment: @JohnEasley: That solution will block the GUI thread during the animation, which IMHO is a rather big drawback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is actually pretty easy.

Probably the simplest way is to base the solution on a `TTimer` which fires some 30 times per second or so, each time updating the form's size.

We just have to settle for a mapping *T* from time to size (width or height), so that *T*(0) is the original size, *T*(1) is the final, target size, and *T*(*t*) is the intermediate size at time *t*, normalized to [0, 1].

Here the simplest approach would be to let the size grow or shrink linearly with time. However, this looks bad. Instead, we should use some [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) to make the speed slow at the beginning and the end and maximal at *t* = 0.5. My favourite sigmoid function is the [inverse tangent function](https://algosim.org/doc/arctan.html), but we could equally well use the [hyperbolic tangent function](https://algosim.org/doc/tanh.html) or the [error function](https://algosim.org/doc/erf.html).

Now, if `FFrames[i]` is the size of the `i`th frame, then

```pascal
var F := 1 / ArcTan(Gamma);

for var i := 0 to High(FFrames) do
begin
  var t := i / High(FFrames);         // [0, 1]
      t := 2*t - 1;                   // [-1, 1]
      t := F*ArcTan(Gamma*t);         // sigmoid transformation
      t := (t + 1) / 2;               // [0, 1]
  FFrames[i] := Round((1 - t) * AFrom + t * ATo);
end;
```

computes the trajectory according to this scheme. Notice that `FFrames[i]` is a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of the initial and final sizes.

The following component uses this code to implement animated resizing:

```pascal
unit WindowAnimator;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Types, Classes, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TWindowAnimator = class(TComponent)
  strict private
  type
    TAxis = (axWidth, axHeight);
  const
    DEFAULT_GAMMA = 10;
    DEFAULT_DURATION = 1000 {ms};
    FrameCount = 256;
  var
    FTimer: TTimer;
    FGamma: Integer;
    FDuration: Integer {ms};
    FFrames: array[0..FrameCount - 1] of Integer;
    FAxis: TAxis;
    FTarget: Integer;
    FAnimStart,
    FAnimEnd: TDateTime;
    FForm: TCustomForm;
    FBeforeProc, FAfterProc: TProc;
    procedure TimerProc(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Plot(AFrom, ATo: Integer);
    procedure Stop;
    procedure Animate(ABeforeProc: TProc = nil; AAfterProc: TProc = nil);
    procedure DoBegin;
    procedure DoFinish;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure AnimateWidth(ANewWidth: Integer; ABeforeProc: TProc = nil; AAfterProc: TProc = nil);
    procedure AnimateHeight(ANewHeight: Integer; ABeforeProc: TProc = nil; AAfterProc: TProc = nil);
  published
    property Gamma: Integer read FGamma write FGamma default DEFAULT_GAMMA;
    property Duration {ms}: Integer read FDuration write FDuration default DEFAULT_DURATION;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Math, DateUtils;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2020', [TWindowAnimator]);
end;

{ TWindowAnimator }

procedure TWindowAnimator.Animate(ABeforeProc, AAfterProc: TProc);
begin

  if FForm = nil then
    Exit;

  FBeforeProc := ABeforeProc;
  FAfterProc := AAfterProc;

  DoBegin;
  FAnimStart := Now;
  FAnimEnd := IncMilliSecond(FAnimStart, FDuration);
  FTimer.Enabled := True;

end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.AnimateHeight(ANewHeight: Integer;
  ABeforeProc, AAfterProc: TProc);
begin

  if FForm = nil then
    Exit;

  Stop;
  FAxis := axHeight;
  Plot(FForm.Height, ANewHeight);
  Animate(ABeforeProc, AAfterProc);

end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.AnimateWidth(ANewWidth: Integer;
  ABeforeProc, AAfterProc: TProc);
begin

  if FForm = nil then
    Exit;

  Stop;
  FAxis := axWidth;
  Plot(FForm.Width, ANewWidth);
  Animate(ABeforeProc, AAfterProc);

end;

constructor TWindowAnimator.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  if AOwner is TCustomForm then
    FForm := TCustomForm(AOwner);
  FGamma := DEFAULT_GAMMA;
  FDuration := DEFAULT_DURATION;
  FTimer := TTimer.Create(Self);
  FTimer.Interval := 30;
  FTimer.OnTimer := TimerProc;
  FTimer.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.DoBegin;
begin
  if Assigned(FBeforeProc) then
    FBeforeProc();
end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.DoFinish;
begin
  if Assigned(FAfterProc) then
    FAfterProc();
end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.Plot(AFrom, ATo: Integer);
begin

  FTarget := ATo;

  var F := 1 / ArcTan(Gamma);

  for var i := 0 to High(FFrames) do
  begin
    var t := i / High(FFrames);         // [0, 1]
        t := 2*t - 1;                   // [-1, 1]
        t := F*ArcTan(Gamma*t);         // sigmoid transformation
        t := (t + 1) / 2;               // [0, 1]
    FFrames[i] := Round((1 - t) * AFrom + t * ATo);
  end;

end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.Stop;
begin
  FTimer.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TWindowAnimator.TimerProc(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var LNow := Now;

  if (FForm = nil) or (FAnimEnd = 0.0) then
  begin
    FTimer.Enabled := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  if LNow > FAnimEnd then // play it safe
  begin
    FTimer.Enabled := False;
    case FAxis of
      axWidth:
        FForm.Width := FTarget;
      axHeight:
        FForm.Height := FTarget;
    end;
    DoFinish;
    Exit;
  end;

  var t := MilliSecondsBetween(LNow, FAnimStart) / MilliSecondsBetween(FAnimStart, FAnimEnd);
  var i := EnsureRange(Round(t * High(FFrames)), 0, High(FFrames));

  case FAxis of
    axWidth:
      FForm.Width := FFrames[i];
    axHeight:
      FForm.Height := FFrames[i];
  end;

end;

end.
```

To use this component, simply drop it on a form and use its public methods:

```pascal
procedure AnimateWidth(ANewWidth: Integer; ABeforeProc: TProc = nil;
  AAfterProc: TProc = nil);
procedure AnimateHeight(ANewHeight: Integer; ABeforeProc: TProc = nil;
  AAfterProc: TProc = nil);
```

The optional `TProc` references let you run some code before and/or after the animation; typically, you want to populate any newly obtained client area after an increase in size and hide some content before a reduction in size.

Here's the component in action, showing and hiding a "Details" text:

[image: Screen recording]

Here's a more complicated example with a three-stage input procedure:

[image: Screen recording]

The total duration of the animation, as well as the sharpness of the sigmoid function, can be adjusted using the component's published properties.

Comment: Bravo, +one!  Curiously, viewing the animation on SO is making me feel queasy ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.SmoothResizeFormTo(const ToSize: integer);
var
  CurrentHeight: integer;
  Step: integer;
begin
  while Height <> ToSize do
  begin
    CurrentHeight := Form1.Height;

    // this is the trick which both accelerates initially then 
    // decelerates as the form reaches its target size
    Step := (ToSize - CurrentHeight) div 3; 

    // this allows for both collapse and expand by using Absolute
    // calculated value
    if (Step = 0) and (Abs(ToSize - CurrentHeight) > 0) then
    begin
      Step := ToSize - CurrentHeight;
      Sleep(50); // adjust for smoothness
    end;

    if Step <> 0 then
    begin
      Height := Height + Step;
      sleep(50); // adjust for smoothness
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCollapseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SmoothResizeFormTo(100);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnExpandClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SmoothResizeFormTo(800);   
end;
```

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956429/2689204) without any timers ;)

[image]

Comment: I don't like this approach because it will block the UI thread during the animation. I am using a timer not because I want to make it complicated or because I don't know of any alternative, but because of the quality of the result! With a timer, the message pump will be active during the entire animation. Your image is misleading, because it is from Windows and not at all from your code. Using your code, the progress bar would freeze during the resize. Also, your code doesn't use a sigmoid function.